# Scala REPL personalization for internal DSL

Tags: scala, dsl, read-eval-print-loop, personalization

On personalizing Scala REPL for internal DSL, from [create-your-custom-scala-repl](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/create-your-custom-scala-repl/)

```
import scala.tools.nsc.Settings
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop

object TestConsole extends App {
  val settings = new Settings
  settings.usejavacp.value = true
  settings.deprecation.value = true

  new SampleILoop().process(settings)
}

class SampleILoop extends ILoop {
  override def prompt = "myDSL $  "

  addThunk {
    intp.beQuietDuring {
      intp.addImports("my.dsl._")
    }
  }
}
```

noticed that `addThunk` is not supported in 2.11.* .

Thus how to load `myDSL.jar` or `import my.dsl._` into a personalized REPL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stick init code in a file, similar to "-i":

```
import scala.tools.nsc.Settings
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop

object TestConsole extends App {
  val settings = new Settings
  settings.usejavacp.value = true
  settings.deprecation.value = true

  new sys.SystemProperties += ("scala.repl.autoruncode" -> "myrepl.init")

  new SampleILoop().process(settings)
}

class SampleILoop extends ILoop {
  override def prompt = "myDSL $  "
}
```

Or:

```
object TestConsole extends App {
  val settings = new Settings
  settings.usejavacp.value = true
  settings.deprecation.value = true

  new sys.SystemProperties += (
    "scala.repl.autoruncode" -> "myrepl.init",
    "scala.shell.prompt" -> "myDSL $ "
  )

  new scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop process settings
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks; how would the contents of `myrepl.init` as a replacement of `intp.addImports("my.dsl._")` ?

Comment: Each line of the file is run as `intp.interpret`; looks like those autorun commands go in command history.

Comment: Tried command `scala TestConsole.jar -cp myDSL.jar` ; also in `myrepl.init` added `import my.dsl._` yet could not get DSL related classes...

Comment: By inserting (terse) DSL code in myrepl.init it works.

Comment: I also refreshed my memory how to do it with sbt. Use `settings.embeddedDefaults` and don't set `usejavacp`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25331737/1296806

Comment: The  "extends App" form only works for me if I compile it and then run it in two steps.  Treating this as a script and running directly with "scala" doesn't work for me; I had to replace the "extends App" with an explicitly defined main method.